# Equivalent of 'compileOnly' in Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, build.gradle, aar, android.mk

I have a pre-built java library as a compile time dependency for Android library project(AAR). So while building it in Android Studio, 'compileOnly' is used so that the same gets linked in runtime when deployed with an APK.

However, I should also write an equivalent Android.mk for the library project. I am not able to find any reference to include a prebuilt java library in Android.mk. Can someone help me on this part.

I tried using LOCAL_PREBUILT_JAVA_LIBRARIES attribute, but the system threw an error:
error: dont use LOCAL_PREBUILT_JAVA_LIBRARIES anymore LOCAL_PATH=xxx.

This kind of dependency linking may look strange. Let me give some insight into it also. Basically I am building an application that has one small part being developed by a third party. The setter interface APIs for the third party are shipped in by me in the form of a .jar file so that they use the same as a compile time dependency and build an AAR out of it.

Now the third party project is to be included in my project build(AOSP). This brings a dependency that their module should be compiled for the AAR to get generated and my project uses that AAR to generate the APK.

For the AAR to get compiled and built, I need to link the prebuilt java interface library that is shipped in by me(mentioned in the first step).

Need an equivalent of 'compileOnly' used in build.gradle.